# Copy value of the previous array for preceding 0 in swift 4

Tags: swift3

In swift I have an array like this:

```
var array = [ 70, 75, 0, 0, 0, 87, 90, 85, 0]
```

What I want to do is when the value is 0 it will copy the previous first value which is not equal to 0. So the output will become:

```
[ 70, 75,75, 75, 75, 87, 90, 85, 85]
```

I’ve tried this code below:

```
func fillingEmpValues(dataArray:[Int]) -> [Int?] {

  var newValue = [Int]()            
  var array = dataArray   

  for (index, var element) in array.reversed().enumerated() {
     if (element == 0) { // if element is 0
         if(index != 0) { // if the index is not 0 proceed
              array[index] = (dataArray.reversed()[index-1])
         }
      }
  }
  return newValue
}
```

But the codes above is not working as I expected the output is still the same. What am i MISSING? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because nothing is appended to `newValue`. Please notice the yellow warnings.

My suggestion uses a temporary variable (`temp`).

In the loop

- if the value != 0 the value is appended and the temporary variable is set to the value.
- if the value == 0 the temporary variable is appended.

---

```
func fillingEmpValues(dataArray:[Int]) -> [Int] {

    var newValue = [Int]()
    var temp = 0

    for element in dataArray {
        if element != 0 {
            newValue.append(element)
            temp = element
        } else {
            newValue.append(temp)
        }
    }
    return newValue
}

let array = [ 70, 75, 0, 0, 0, 87, 90, 85, 0]
let filledArray = fillingEmpValues(dataArray: array) // [70, 75, 75, 75, 75, 87, 90, 85, 85]
```

Note: Why is your return value `[Int?]`? Optionals are not involved at all.

**Edit:**

The other condition in the comments can be accomplished with

```
func fillingEmpValues(dataArray:[Int]) -> [Int] {

    var newValue = [Int]()
    var temp = dataArray.first{ $0 != 0 } ?? 0

    for (index, element) in dataArray.enumerated() {
        if element != 0 {
            newValue.append(element)
        } else {
            temp = dataArray.dropFirst(index).first{ $0 != 0 } ?? temp
            newValue.append(temp)
        }
    }
    return newValue
}

let array = [ 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 87, 90, 85, 0]
let filledArray = fillingEmpValues(dataArray: array) // [83, 83, 83, 87, 87, 87, 90, 85, 85]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me what is wrong. But what if the value is `[ 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 87, 90, 85, 0]`.  If you notice the first index is 0. Now what if the output I want to achieve is `[ 83, 83, 83, 87, 87, 87, 90, 85, 85]`. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: It's possible, but seems a little strange that if the first value is zero, that you always want to copy non-zero values from later in the array and if it's not zero, always copy non-zero values from earlier in the array. And then what do you want to do if there are zeros at both ends, e.g. `[0, 75, 0, 87, 0]`?

Comment: In the case if the first index is 0 then it will copy the next value which is not equal to zero. And if the end is 0 it will copy the previous value which is not equal to zero. Maybe I have to make conditions for this.

Comment: Yeah that is what I want to achieve. Actually I am making condition right now and I have lot's of `if ` statement compare to your answer. If I can only vote two times. Thank you @vadian

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest using `reduce(into:)`:

```
let array = [70, 75, 0, 0, 0, 87, 90, 85, 0]
let array2 = array.reduce(into: [Int]()) { (result, value) in
    if value == 0 {
        result.append(result.last ?? 0)
    } else {
        result.append(value)
    }
}
```

Yielding:

> [70, 75, 75, 75, 75, 87, 90, 85, 85]